# Calculating Proportion of Column Total compared to total of all columns

Tags: r, matrix, col

I'm attempting to calculate the Proportion of a column total compared to the total of all columns.

The Document Term Matrix I'm working with is quite large, causing any tests I run incorrectly to basically crash Rstudio.

Here is my working code so far:

```
randomSample = read.csv("randomSample2016.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(randomSample)
randomSample$tweet <- as.character(randomSample$tweet)

randomSample$tweetlength <- nchar(randomSample$tweet)

hist(randomSample$tweetlength)


library("tm")

## Use the tm library to construct a document-term matrix of term 
frequencies

randomSample_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(randomSample$tweet))
print(randomSample_corpus)

inspect(randomSample_corpus[1:3])

#clean up corpus
#make all letters lowercase
randomSample_corpus_clean <- tm_map(randomSample_corpus, tolower)

#Remove Numbers
randomSample_corpus_clean <- tm_map(randomSample_corpus_clean, 
removeNumbers)

#Remove punctuation
randomSample_corpus_clean <- tm_map(randomSample_corpus_clean, 
removePunctuation)

#Remove stop words
randomSample_corpus_clean <- tm_map(randomSample_corpus_clean, removeWords, 
stopwords())

#remove unneeded whitespace
randomSample_corpus_clean <- tm_map(randomSample_corpus_clean, 
stripWhitespace)

#Inspect cleaned corpus
 inspect(randomSample_corpus_clean[1:3])

#Create document term matrix 
randomSample_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(randomSample_corpus_clean)

#convert to R matrix
dtm2 <- as.matrix(randomSample_dtm)

#obtain individual word frequencies
frequency <- colSums(dtm2)
```

This allows me to get the total frequency of all words in dtm2, however when I try to add a new row for column totals (`dtm2$newcolumn <- 0`) I end up with an insane amount of ram usage.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `colSums` returns a named-array. what you want is

```
as.matrix(randomSample_dtm) %>% {
    rbind(., rbind(colSums(.) %>% as.numeric)) %>% as.matrix()
}
```

Comment: Has this added a new row (of colSums) to randomSample_dtm?
Inserting this has outputted a huge collection of random words from the DTM